Book with watercolor cover from early to mid 2000s
I've been trying to find a book that I started to read when I was a teen.  I don't remember what it was called but I believe i set it down because it might've been to mature for me at the time
What I remember is the cover was super pretty watercolor looking with pinks and golds
It started off with a youngish woman who's super pretty blonde hair,  slim (you know the type in books) in a tree (I think) and these men were coming by horse to test for magic, this girl to her surprise had this light magic that came out described as moving like what's inside a kaleidoscope.
She ends up being taken to this kingdom to be taught how to control it  with one other girl who excels at the lessons. The blonde girls powers get dampened because she's inside all the time.  It's figured out that she needs to be outside to be free to harness her gifts...
Eventually she's on a journey with a man she's instantly attracted to they get stuck in a cave.. and stuff happens that I think I blocked out but they're engaged after and I never picked the book up again and I don't think I was anywhere near finishing it.

Was his name Flynn Rider?
